# How can I set up a button handler to remove a parent table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML & jQuery project, and everything currently works perfectly for what I want them to do. What I need right now is to add a Delete/Remove Button that is linked to this line:

```
'<button class="removeThis" onclick="removeThis(' + tr.length + ')">Delete</button >' +
```

As you can see the buttons are visible only if you click the add button and create a new TR with values.

I tried creating a jQuery function:

```
function removeThis(a) {
    $('tr-' + 'a').remove();
}
```

But of course, it's not doing what I need it to do.

Can anyone help me resolving this?

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.hide', function () {
        console.log('hide');
        $('form').hide();
    });

    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.add', function () {
        console.log('add');
        var edit = $('#edit');
        editRow = $('#editRow');

        edit.show();
        if (!($('#addNew').length)) {
            edit.append('<input type="button" id="addNew" onclick="addNewTr()" value="Add" name="submit" />');
        }

        if (editRow) {
            editRow.remove();
        }

        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
    });

    $('#show').click(function () {
        //$('form').show();
        //$('#btd1').val('Vlad');
        //$('#btd2').val('Andrei');
        //$('#btd3').val('vTask');
        //  $('#btd4').val('Ceva');
        //$('#btd5').val('Alceva');
    });
});

function edit(a) {
    var edit = $('#edit');
        addNew = $('#addNew');
        editRow = $('#editRow');

    edit.show();
    if (addNew) {
        addNew.remove();
    }

    if (editRow.length) {
        editRow.replaceWith('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Edit" name="submit" />');
    } else  {
        edit.append('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Edit" name="submit" />');
    }

    $.each($('.tr-' + a).find('td'), function (key, val) {
        $('form#edit input[type=text]').eq(key).val($(val).text());
    });
}

function save(a) {
    var tr = $('tr');
    valid = true;
    message = '';

    $('form#edit input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please complete all the colums' + inputName + '\n';
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
    } else {
        for (var q = 1; q < $('.tr-' + a + ' td').length; q++) {
            $('.tr-' + a + ' td:nth-child(' + q + ')').html($('#btd' + q).val());
        }
        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
        $('#editRow').remove();
    }
}

function addNewTr() {
    var tr = $('tr');
    valid = true;
    message = '';

    $('form#edit input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
    } else {
        $('table tbody').append('' +
            '<tr class="tr-' + tr.length + '">' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td class="buttons">' +
            '<button class="removeThis" onclick="removeThis(' + tr.length + ')">Delete</button >' +
            '<button class="edit" onclick="edit(' + tr.length + ')">Edit</button >' +
            '</td >' +
            '</tr>' +
            '');
        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
    }
}

function removeThis(a) {
    $('tr-' + 'a').remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >
<link href="../css/vtask.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title >vTask</title >
<h1 id="hh1">[<a id="vt1">vTask</a>]</h1>
</head >
<body>

<table class="greenTable">
<tr><td colspan="6"><form id="edit" action="" method="post" hidden >
<label for="btd1" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="btd1" value="" placeholder="Name">
<label for="btd2" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Secondary Name" id="btd2" value="" placeholder="Secondary Name">
<label for="btd3" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="btd3" value="" placeholder="Email">
<label for="btd4" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Telephone" id="btd4" value="" placeholder="Telephone">
<label for="btd5" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Password" id="btd5" value="" placeholder="Password">
</form ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%">Name</td>
<td width="10%">Secondary Name</td>
<td width="10%">Email</td>
<td width="10%">Telephone</td>
<td width="10%">Password</td>
<td class="buttons" width="20%"><button class="add" >Add</button >
<button class="hide" >Hide</button ></td>
</tr>    
</table >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body >
</html >
```

I don't want any of the other functions to be deleted. 
BTW the Delete button is already added with ID removeThis.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you mean this?:  `'tr-' + a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the quotes from 'a':

```
function removeThis(a) {
    $('.tr-' + a).remove();
}
```

EDIT: This snippet is totally working! I did need to add a dot before 'tr' since it is a class.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.hide', function () {
        console.log('hide');
        $('form').hide();
    });

    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.add', function () {
        console.log('add');
        var edit = $('#edit');
        editRow = $('#editRow');

        edit.show();
        if (!($('#addNew').length)) {
            edit.append('<input type="button" id="addNew" onclick="addNewTr()" value="Add" name="submit" />');
        }

        if (editRow) {
            editRow.remove();
        }

        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
    });

    $('#show').click(function () {
        //$('form').show();
        //$('#btd1').val('Vlad');
        //$('#btd2').val('Andrei');
        //$('#btd3').val('vTask');
        //  $('#btd4').val('Ceva');
        //$('#btd5').val('Alceva');
    });
});

function edit(a) {
    var edit = $('#edit');
        addNew = $('#addNew');
        editRow = $('#editRow');

    edit.show();
    if (addNew) {
        addNew.remove();
    }

    if (editRow.length) {
        editRow.replaceWith('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Edit" name="submit" />');
    } else  {
        edit.append('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Edit" name="submit" />');
    }

    $.each($('.tr-' + a).find('td'), function (key, val) {
        $('form#edit input[type=text]').eq(key).val($(val).text());
    });
}

function save(a) {
    var tr = $('tr');
    valid = true;
    message = '';

    $('form#edit input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please complete all the colums' + inputName + '\n';
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
    } else {
        for (var q = 1; q < $('.tr-' + a + ' td').length; q++) {
            $('.tr-' + a + ' td:nth-child(' + q + ')').html($('#btd' + q).val());
        }
        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
        $('#editRow').remove();
    }
}

function addNewTr() {
    var tr = $('tr');
    valid = true;
    message = '';

    $('form#edit input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
    } else {
        $('table tbody').append('' +
            '<tr class="tr-' + tr.length + '">' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td class="buttons">' +
            '<button class="removeThis" onclick="removeThis(' + tr.length + ')">Delete</button >' +
            '<button class="edit" onclick="edit(' + tr.length + ')">Edit</button >' +
            '</td >' +
            '</tr>' +
            '');
        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
    }
}

function removeThis(a) {
    alert('.tr-'+a);
    $('.tr-' + a).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >
<link href="../css/vtask.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title >vTask</title >
<h1 id="hh1">[<a id="vt1">vTask</a>]</h1>
</head >
<body>

<table class="greenTable">
<tr><td colspan="6"><form id="edit" action="" method="post" hidden >
<label for="btd1" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="btd1" value="" placeholder="Name">
<label for="btd2" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Secondary Name" id="btd2" value="" placeholder="Secondary Name">
<label for="btd3" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="btd3" value="" placeholder="Email">
<label for="btd4" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Telephone" id="btd4" value="" placeholder="Telephone">
<label for="btd5" ></label >
    <input type="text" name="Password" id="btd5" value="" placeholder="Password">
</form ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%">Name</td>
<td width="10%">Secondary Name</td>
<td width="10%">Email</td>
<td width="10%">Telephone</td>
<td width="10%">Password</td>
<td class="buttons" width="20%"><button class="add" >Add</button >
<button class="hide" >Hide</button ></td>
</tr>    
</table >
<button class="removeThis" onclick="removeThis(' + tr.length + ')">Delete</button >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body >
</html >
```

Comment: Still not working tried that also. forgot to mention sorry

Comment: Great, Worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this without jQuery at all, and I highly recommend that.

```
function removeThis(e){
  const parentTd  = e.parentNode;
  const parentTr = parentTd.parentNode;
  const parentTable = parentTr.parentNode;

  return parentTable.removeChild(parentTr);
}
```

And on your button you do

```
 <button onClick='removeThis(this)'>Delete me</button>
```

This way you create a testable and reusable function that you can use to remove all DOM Elements.

Oh, and by the way, this way you work from inside-out rather than querying the whole document for the element intended to remove.

Comment: makes only my Delete button dissapear

Comment: @Andrei224231 oops, I forgot that you need to delete the TR. Well than you need to create a DOM instance of that TR and pass it to removeThis.

Comment: If i would know how to do it :). I just started learning 1 week ago javascript

Comment: You could the button code from this example as-is and do something like this:
`var parentTr = e.parentNode; return parentTr.parentNode.removeChild(parentTr);`

Comment: @Andrei224231 I updated my answer thanks to David Millar response.

Comment: It is working but in the console, I get the error Uncaught TypeError: RemoveThis (....) is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Because you're referencing removeThis() wrong. Make the first R lower case.

Answer (score 2):

Your example function below builds a string `'tr-' + 'a'` which will always just look for `"tr-a"`:

```
function removeThis(a) {
    $('tr-' + 'a').remove();
}
```

Just remove the quotes from around `'a'`:

```
function removeThis(a) {
    $('tr-' + a).remove();
}
```

Comment: You will have to do it this way if you want this approach :

function removeThis(a) {
    $('.greenTable tr:eq('+a+')').remove();
}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around the letter 'a' so you can use the variable there:

```
function removeThis(a) {
    $('.tr-' + a).remove();
}
```

You should also consider using a different way to number the table rows. The row numbers will start to get reused if you delete a row and then add a new one:

```
Row 0, Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, Row 4

Add row. There are 5 rows, so the new row is row 5.
Row 0, Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, Row 4, Row 5

Remove row 1.
Row 0, Row 2, Row 3, Row 4, Row 5

Add row. There are 5 (!!!) rows, so the new row is (also!!!) row 5.
Row 0, Row 2, Row 3, Row 4, Row 5, Row 5
```

Instead of getting a new value for tr every time you add a row, instead consider a global variable that you increment every time you add a row:

```
var rowCounter = 0;

function addNewTr() {
    //snip

    rowCounter++;

    $('table tbody').append('' +
        '<tr class="tr-' + rowCounter + '">' +

    //snip
}
```

Comment: The function removeThis(a) not working. I tried that also

Comment: Sorry @Andrei224231 there was also a missing period at the beginning to denote that you're searching for a class.